# Does importing and using a package count as dynamic linking in scripting languages?

Tags: licensing

In interpreted languages like R and Python if I import and module, and use its functions, is that considered as dynamic linking of my program to that module?

Comment: Why do you care? If it's for legal reasons, that is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Also, if it's for legal reasons, the term "dynamic linking" is not a legal term, and thus irrelevant.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it may be a term that shows up in a license agreement. But in that case the term should be defined in the license. And if that's the case it doesn't matter what we think it means.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it is a kind of dynamic linking (unless you import a module that's statically linked into the runtime, which is possible but somewhat unusual). When a python module includes C code, there's actual dynamic linking involved to access the foreign code.

However, the distinction of dynamic versus static linking is not fully applicable for interpreted languages where you always share the program source and not a compiled binary. So you should really ask yourself why anybody wants to know and whether they probably misunderstood something.

Comment: If you cut and paste the library code into your own source file thats statically linked ;-)